# How do i connect/disconnect bluetooth speakers to my macbook with a shortcut?

Tags: bluetooth

I have bluetooth device (speakers set). I can connect/disconnect them in menu bar. But this is not very comfortable to do. How do i create a shortcut to toggle connection of specific device?